# Linking dependencies for an External Project in CMake

Tags: c, linker, dependencies, cmake

I have the following code in my `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
ExternalProject_Add(
    LibSndFile
    URL "http://www.mega-nerd.com/libsndfile/files/libsndfile-1.0.25.tar.gz"
    CONFIGURE_COMMAND ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/LibSndFile/configure --prefix=<INSTALL_DIR>
    BUILD_COMMAND ${MAKE}
    SOURCE_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/LibSndFile
    UPDATE_COMMAND ""
    INSTALL_COMMAND ""
    LOG_DOWNLOAD ON
    LOG_CONFIGURE ON
    LOG_BUILD ON
)
```

Everything configures and builds just fine, until the project is ready for linking.  Because LibSndFile depends on `flac`, `libogg`, and `libvorbis` it needs to link to those, but it can't see them.

How can I make it so that my External Project can link to those dependencies installed on my system (is there some `LINK_LIBRARY` option I'm not seeing)?  If they weren't installed on my system, how would I go about linking them to LibSndFile?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the safest way to do this I found is to use another `ExternalProject_Add` for the dependencies of LibSndFile:

```
find_package(FLAC) # test if FLAC is installed on the system
if(${FLAC_FOUND}) # do something if it is found, maybe tell the user
else(${FLAC_FOUND}) # FLAC isn't installed on the system and needs to be downloaded
    ExternalProject_Add(
        FLAC
        URL "http://downloads.xiph.org/releases/flac/flac-1.3.0.tar.xz"
        CONFIGURE_COMMAND ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/flac/configure --prefix=<INSTALL_DIR>
        BUILD_COMMAND ${MAKE}
        SOURCE_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/flac
        UPDATE_COMMAND ""
        INSTALL_COMMAND ""
        LOG_DOWNLOAD ON
        LOG_CONFIGURE ON
        LOG_BUILD ON
    )
endif(${FLAC_FOUND})
```

And then use the `DEPENDS` directive in LibSndFile to point it to the targets on which the project depends.

```
ExternalProject_Add(
    LibSndFile
    DEPENDS FLAC libogg libvorbis
    URL "http://www.mega-nerd.com/libsndfile/files/libsndfile-1.0.25.tar.gz"
    CONFIGURE_COMMAND ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/LibSndFile/configure --prefix=<INSTALL_DIR>
    BUILD_COMMAND ${MAKE}
    SOURCE_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/LibSndFile
    UPDATE_COMMAND ""
    INSTALL_COMMAND ""
    LOG_DOWNLOAD ON
    LOG_CONFIGURE ON
    LOG_BUILD ON
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Running configure from libsndfile followed by `make install` (I believe) produces `sndfile.pc` which contains the information you want for linking.

How about extracting the library settings from this file? You can add custom steps to `ExternalProject_Add` according to the [documentation](http://www.kitware.com/media/html/BuildingExternalProjectsWithCMake2.8.html).

Comment: This doesn't really answer my question... I need those dependencies in order to run `make` without any errors.

Comment: You need to find those dependencies before running ExternalProject_Add and tell configure about it. I assumed that you knew this and your problem was how to link with the libraries used by libsndfile.

Comment: And how would I go about telling configure about them?

Comment: Using options to configure or by setting CFLAGS/LDFLAGS env variables before calling the configure script.

Comment: I feel like there are lower scope variables that I should be able to set to accomplish what I am looking for.